# Understanding scikit's decision tree - inconsistent learning

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have been using the package `tsfresh` to find relevant features for time-series. It outputs approximately 300 "relevant" features that pass a p-test threshold for predictability for each feature. When I train a classifier using scikit's `DecisionTreeClassifier()` I get some odd results. Each time I execute the learning of the tree it returns a tree with only two levels, and every time the features it uses are different. I am befuddled. The tree does a nice job every time but am I not seeing all the levels?
Using this code:

```
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.tree import _tree
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_filtered, y, test_size=.2)
cl = DecisionTreeClassifier()
cl.fit(X_train, y_train)
tree.export_graphviz(cl,out_file='tree.dot',feature_names=X.columns)
```

where `len(X.colums)` is over 300 returns a decision tree of two levels every time.

Answer (score 0):

The output of this line is random:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_filtered, y, test_size=.2)
```

That is, every time you split the data in train and test sets, you get different sets. You can use the `random_state` attribute to obtain a predictable split:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_filtered, y, test_size=.2, random_state=4)
```

Doing so should give you the same split features always for the tree.

Comment: This helps but what I am curious about is in the `DecisionTreeClassifier` class. It returns different features. I have a large test set so I am not sure what is going on.

Comment: If you have different training sets each time you can get different selected features. Did you try setting `random_state` like I said?

Comment: Yes, using `random_state` I get the same states but their importances vary wildly.